# toggle text by clicking on hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to toggle the text on/Off in html without hiding any of the disabled functions. The following code can toggle `on` and `off` but the problem is this:

- It cannot toggle without hiding another word. I.e. when I press turn on it hides The Turn Off function.
- When I add the toggle method for another line item it only toggles the first line item. So it doesn't matter if I add it to line items five rows past the original it will only trigger the original.

```js
function toggle() {
  var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
  var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
  if (ele.style.display == "block") {
    ele.style.display = "none";
    text.innerHTML = "On";
  } else {
    ele.style.display = "block";
    text.innerHTML = "Turn Off";
  }
}
```

```html
 <h1>Services</h1>

<h2>Subscribed Services</h2>

<ul>
  <li>Geolocation -<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">On</a> 

    <div id="toggleText" style="display: none"></div>
  </li>

  <li>E-Mail Messaging -<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">On</a>

    <div id="toggleText" style="display: none"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all some annotation to your code:

IDs have to be [unique](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) ! So use classes instead.

I hope I understand it correctly what you are trying to achieve:

HTML:

```
<h2>Subscribed Services</h2>
<ul>
  <li>Geolocation -<a class="displayText" href="javascript:void(0);">On</a>
  </li>
  <li>E-Mail Messaging -<a class="displayText" href="javascript:void(0);">On</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$('.displayText').on('click', function(e) {

  $(this).text(function(i, s) {
      return s === 'On' ? 'Off' : 'On';
    });

});
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/wv5oxcu3/)

---

Reference:

[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)